# unable to get button click working

Tags: java, android, layout, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have my java file as

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class ThemesActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_themes);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_themes);
    sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().
getSharedPreferences("MyNumbers", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int bg = sharedPreferences.getInt("background_resource",
 R.color.backYellow);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(bg);
}

public void yellowClick(View view){
    sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().
getSharedPreferences("MyNumbers", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("background_resource", R.color.backYellow);
    editor.putInt("button_resource", R.color.buttonYellow);
    editor.apply();
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.backYellow);
}

public void redClick(View view){
    sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().
getSharedPreferences("MyNumbers", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("background_resource", R.color.backRed);
    editor.putInt("button_resource", R.color.buttonRed);
    editor.apply();
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.backRed);
}

public void blueClick(View view){
    sharedPreferences =      getApplicationContext().
 getSharedPreferences("MyNumbers", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("background_resource", R.color.backBlue);
    editor.putInt("button_resource", R.color.buttonBlue);
    editor.apply();
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.backBlue);
}

public void greenClick(View view){
    sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().
 getSharedPreferences("MyNumbers", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("background_resource", R.color.backGreen);
    editor.putInt("button_resource", R.color.buttonGreen);
    editor.apply();
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.backGreen);
}

}
```

And resource file as,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.dhritiman.any.ThemesActivity">

<!-- Login progress -->


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/blueButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:onClick="blueClick"
            android:text="Blue"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/yellowButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:onClick="yellowClick"
            android:text="Yellow"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/redButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:contextClickable="false"
            android:linksClickable="false"
            android:onClick="redClick"
            android:text="Red"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/greenButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:onClick="greenClick"
            android:text="Green"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help, my logcat is showing process pointer 0 and process pointer 1
I mean it is taking only touch input and not button click input when button is clicked
I have checked everything but not able to find the problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have any reference to the button itself - you must add something like - `Button btn = findViewById(R.id.your_button_name);`. And why do you use `onStart()` and not placing all that code at `onCreate()`?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but if I'm following you correctly, remove `android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"` from the `<RelativeLayout>` in your layout XML.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialize your views and layouts inside `onCreate()` which is called at the creation of activity, `onStart()` is called when the activity is visible to user.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_themes);
    // add here
    sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyNumbers", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int bg = sharedPreferences.getInt("background_resource",R.color.backYellow);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(bg);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // move to onCreate
}
```

Comment: can you say me what do you mean by initializing my views?

Comment: putting your layout file inside `onCreate()` !

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick will work fine just Log any custome message on that but u just initialize your setContentView(R.layout.activity_themes) inside onCreate as your code work now also but init all view component should be initialize inside onCreate method

Thanks!